# How to make an array of useForms from react-hook-form to create a mult call action

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

I'm using typescript, useForm to created a form to fill out for each entry and to put each entry in an array to make a batch entry function. Having trouble finding docs that further expand on useFrom to create an array of form inputs.

My form type is:

```
type DirectFormData = {
  nftContractAddress: string;
  tokenId: string;
  currencyContractAddress: string;
  price: string;
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
};
```

Then I have the function to fill out and submit the form here:

```
    const { register: registerBatch2, handleSubmit: handleSubmitBatch2 } =
    useForm<DirectFormData>({
      defaultValues: {
        nftContractAddress: ETHDrop,
        tokenId: nft.metadata.id,
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
        currencyContractAddress: "0x72F60F2F9695C5911bA57ee43339AD82ce8ABB6A",
        price: "0",
      },
    });
```

I'm trying to figure out how to set up and array of the above useForm for mutliple forms being submitted into one action call using the following function.

```
const listings = [];

  async function handleSubmissionBatch(data: DirectFormData, count: number) {
    const listings = createListingArray(data, count);
    await checkAndProvideApproval();
    const txResult = await marketplace?.directListings.createListingsBatch(listings);
  
    return txResult;
  }
```

What is a way to go about putting the forms into an array?

Maybe I could try something like this but how would I structure the type DirectFormData?

```
    const { register: registerBatch2, handleSubmit: handleSubmitBatch2 } =
    useForm<DirectFormData>({
      defaultValues: {
        listings: [
          {
            listing: '1',
            values: {
              nftContractAddress: ETHDrop,
              tokenId: nft.metadata.id,
              startDate: new Date(),
              endDate: new Date(),
              currencyContractAddress: "0x72F60F2F9695C5911bA57ee43339AD82ce8ABB6A",
              price: "0",
            }
          },
          {
            listing: '2',
            values: {
              nftContractAddress: ETHDrop,
              tokenId: nft.metadata.id,
              startDate: new Date(),
              endDate: new Date(),
              currencyContractAddress: "0x72F60F2F9695C5911bA57ee43339AD82ce8ABB6A",
              price: "0",
            }
          },
          {
            listing: '3',
            values: {
              nftContractAddress: ETHDrop,
              tokenId: nft.metadata.id,
              startDate: new Date(),
              endDate: new Date(),
              currencyContractAddress: "0x72F60F2F9695C5911bA57ee43339AD82ce8ABB6A",
              price: "0",
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    });
```

Comment: Seems like maybe `useFieldArray()` is intended for this purpose? https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray/